# Getting connectionstring to database causes 'Access violation' in my web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am learning the basics of creating a web API using ASP.NET core, where I include DTO to transfer objects from my database to my API.

When I try to add a connectionstring to my app `app` I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
> The program '[35976] StudentAPI.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

After I recieved this error, I debbuged my program to see what caussed this issue, and I found out that the following would cause it crash:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiContext")));
```

If I removed this from my `program.cs` the access violation would be resolved and the program can run. But without the connectionstring I cannot access my database.

For context, here is my `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StudentAPI.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiContext")));

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

If anyone have any solutions or anything that may help, it would be appreciated

**EDIT**

As this is for localhost, there is nothing of interrest in my connectionstring located in appsettings.development.json, but you can see it here:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebApiContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AfleveringsProjectet;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

I also share my DatabaseContext here:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;

namespace StudentAPI.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Laver en entititet af Student, hvor StudentId er primaryKey
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasKey(s => s.StudentId);

            // Laver en entititet af Couses, hvor Courseid er primaryKey
            modelBuilder.Entity<Courses>()
                .HasKey(c => c.CourseId);

            //Laver PrimaryKey på både StudenId & CourseId
            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
                .HasKey(cl => new { cl.StudentId, cl.CourseId });

            // Laver PrimaryKey på Teams
            modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.TeamId });

            // Laver en one-to-many realationship imellem Student & teams. Så ét hold har mange elever men eleverne er på ét hold
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Team)
                .WithMany(t => t.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.TeamId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.Student)
                .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.StudentId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.Courses)
                .WithMany(c => c.StudentCourses)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CourseId);
        }
    }
}
```

The most interresting thig about my dabasecontext would properbly be the constructor...

Comment: Can you show how your ConnectionString is specified in web.config.xml or appFile.config? (You can obfuscate any sensitive data, I'm not interested in the value of ConnectionString, but in the way it is defined)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add the `DbContext` after the app has already been built. Move the line above the `var app = builder.Build();` line.

Answer (score 0):

The line you highlight does 2 things:

```
var s = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiContext");
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(s));
```

Both of these could fail, but I suspect the code producing the access violation  is `AddDbContext` and not `GetConnectionString`.

Try to investigate the ConnectionString you get returned, and see if you can use that result in a mickey mouse example to connect to your database.

Comment: I tried to get my connectionstring, using a configurationbuilder. And I can confirm that the connectionstring i the right one.

So I can only asume that it fails when setting it to the builder.